# How to make pefile python module read multiple executable file in a directory

Tags: python-2.7, python-module, portable-executable

I'm currently working on this python code using pefile python module

```
import pefile

pe =  pefile.PE('C:\Documents and Settings\Zha\Desktop\\test\\firefox.exe')
pe.parse_data_directories()


print '%x' % pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections
```

what I'm trying to do is to collect number of section of all file in the test directory however I need to run hundreds of executable file, is there any faster way to do it? Because the * option does not working.

ps: after few hours I found the answer myself, will post the answer after 8 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours of searching I found it myself lol

```
import glob
import pefile

for filename in glob.iglob('C:\Documents and Settings\Zha\Desktop\\test\*.exe'):
    pe =  pefile.PE(filename)
    pe.parse_data_directories()
    print '%x' % pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections
```